# Staging subdomains when application already has subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, staging

My current Rails application has the following subdomains:

```
ui.myapp.com
api.myapp.com
```

I want to set up a staging environment, and I am wondering what is the best approach in order to set the domains.

Usually, I would do:

```
staging.myapp.com
```

But then, how do I access the UI/API sites?

Is it 'ok' to do:

```
ui.staging.myapp.com
api.staging.myapp.com
```

?

Comment: Yes, this should be perfectly ok. What concerns do you have? Cookie issues?

Comment: Martin Poulsen, I am concerned about SSL certificates not going more than one level deep in subdomains...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: The output from API call is expected in JSON format.

It will not be advisable to use separate subdomain for functionality like api.staging.myapp.com. You can always use the same url for web application and API
Better way would be to use same controller-action from Rails application but instead to return JSON output hash.

For example to get the users, you will have some code in users_controller.rb as

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        render :index
      end
      format.json do
        render :json => {:users => @users}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now here if the request is html it will render the html page else it will return the json response.

staging.myapp.com/users will get you the html page of web application displaying users collection and that of staging.myapp.com/users.json will provide you the json response hash of users collection.

So, you will not need different subdomain to distinguish the api and normal site. But using format of request you can distinguish the functionality.

I hope this answers your question. If you still have any query feel free to ask.

Comment: This might be a good solution for simple situations. But in most setups there is a need to separate web and api controllers because the logic is almost always a bit different and you want to versionate the API.

Comment: @MartinPoulsen Yes, I agree, you may need to have separate controllers but still can have same subdomain. You can use some gem to maintain API related controllers code. Regarding versioned API, you can have version to be passed in parameters like staging.myapp.com/v2/users.